# if A text is found in B class then replace it with C text and html in replace function

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var d = jQuery('.bbp-template-notice p');
        d.text(d.text().trim().replace(/You must be logged in to create new topics./i, "You must be logged in to create new topics. Please  <a href='#pagelink'><font style='font-weight:bold;'>LOGIN HERE</font></a>"));
    });
</script>
```

Right now it displays as:

> You must be logged in to create new topics. Please LOGIN HERE"

It is displaying the html code as it is in frontend. I want the anchor property to work in that class.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan We both are doing at the same time. So even I can tell the same thing! `:P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `html()` method, as `text()` encodes the value provided. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var $d = $('.bbp-template-notice p');
        $d.html(function(i, html) {
            return html.trim().replace(/You must be logged in to create new topics./i, 'You must be logged in to create new topics. Please  <a href="http://foo.com/bar.html"><font style="font-weight: bold;">LOGIN HERE</font></a>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3wpawmv3/)

Comment: please remove my site link in your answer

Comment: error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) in console

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? I added a working example for you.

Comment: thanks rory...But thanga answer is working correctly...Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi, Checked it now your answer is working perfectly better than thanga answer for sure...